# want to redirect to my home page when user reload the page

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect to my home page when user press the refresh button of the browser.

Example. 
when some user is on 2nd page of my application ( like www.mydomain.com/second.php ) and hit the browser refrsh button the i want a javascript pop for confirmation and redirect the user to my application home page ( like www.mydomain.com ) and i want to do it with javascript.

Comment: cool thing.. !! now what have you tried??

Comment: that sounds like a horrible user experience. Please explain *why* you'd want to hijack the user's expectations.

Comment: Don't do that; it's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden input to accomplish this. When the user lands on the page the first time, set the value as `true`. Hidden inputs are normally saved across browser refreshes, so when the page is refreshed, set to check if that hidden input is set to `true` or not. If it is, use `window.location` to redirect the user to the page you want.

This page describes what you're looking for: http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php

Here is an example of that taken directly from this page:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="JavaScript"> <!--
function checkRefresh()
{
    if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "" )
    {
        // This is a fresh page load
        document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";

        // You may want to add code here special for
        // fresh page loads
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a page refresh

        // Insert code here representing what to do on
        // a refresh
    }
} -->
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="JavaScript:checkRefresh();">
    <form name="refreshForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="visited" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I am from the year 2020, this solution no longer works, also please make sure to wash your hands.

Comment: I came from 2021 D: